# How does this follow from Chebyshev's inequality

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, concentration-of-measure

My textbook claims that the following inequality follows from chebshev's inequality

$\int_{|x|\geq B}(1+|x|^{p})dL_{A}\leq B^{-p-2q}\int(1+x^{2(p+q)})dL_{A},$

where $L_{A}$ is the empirical spectral disribution of some random matrix, that is of the form $L_{A}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\delta_{\lambda_{i}}$ where $N$ is the size of the matrix (In fact $L_{A}$ could be any probability measure).

This inequality is not clear for me. I have separated the LHS into a sum of two integrals, for the first integral there is no problem,  for the second I use $g(u)=u^{\frac{2(p+q)}{p}}$ to find

$\int_{|x|\geq B}|x|^{p}dL_{A}\leq \frac{1}{B^{\frac{2(p+q)}{p}}}\int x^{2(p+q)}dL_{A},$

which is not what I want.

Comment: This inequality crops up on page 29 here http://www.umpa.ens-lyon.fr/~aguionne/cours.pdf (in fact a modified version of the above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \int_{|x|\ge B} |x|^p \, dL_A = \int_{|x|\ge B} |x|^{2(q+p)} |x|^{-p-2q} \, dL_A $$
Since $|x|\ge B$ inside the integral, we get $|x|^{-p-2q} \le B^{-p-2q}$ inside the integral.

Comment: Do I need to add more details to get the bounty?  I looked at the book, and it did specify that $B \ge 2$, implied $p \ge 0$, and specified that $q \ge 0$.  That should be enough to complete the claim in the book that $$\int_{|x|\ge B} (1+|x|^p) \, dL_A = 2|B|^{-p-2q} \int_{|x|\ge B} |x|^{2(q+p)} \, dL_A .$$

Comment: I will of course give you the bounty, but can do so only in 3h. :-). Thanks a lot.